# show that the extension $\mathbb{Z}_{2}(X)\supseteq \mathbb{Z}_{2}(X^2+X)$ is Galois

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field

let $K=\mathbb{Z}_{2}(X^2+X)$ and $L=\mathbb{Z}_{2}(X)$. I want to show that $L\supseteq K$ is a Galois extension, but I am stuck on finding a minimal polynomial of $X^2-X$ over $K=\mathbb{Z}_{2}(X^2+X)$.

First I want to construct a polynomial that will have all it's zeros in $L=\mathbb{Z}_{2}(X)$:

$p(t)=t(t+1)-X(X+1)\in \mathbb{Z}_{2}(X^2+X)[t]$
then it's zero is $X=-X$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$

but $X\not\in\mathbb{Z}_{2}(X^2+X)$ so the above polynomial must be irreducible and  $p(t)=min\;pol_{K} (X)$

$L\supseteq K$ is normal and $p^{\prime}(t)=2t+1=1$ and $(p(t),p^{\prime}(t))=1$ so $L\supseteq K$ is also separable. Hence the extension is Galois.

Is this okay?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean $\mathbb{Z}(X)$ (so, rational functions) or $mathbb{Z}[X]$ (polynomials)?

Comment: the first one, both are fields of rational functions with coefficients $\mod 2$

Comment: I'm not an expert, but this seems perfectly fine to me.

Comment: Aside: $\mathbb{F}_2$ or $\mathbb{Z} / 2\mathbb{Z}$ are unambiguous notation for the field of 2 elements: $\mathbb{Z}_2$ could be interpreted as the field of $2$-adic numbers. Or more generally, $\mathbb{F}_q$ for the finite field of $q$ elements, and $\mathbb{Z} / n \mathbb{Z}$ for the ring of integers modulo $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look's ok. Instead of going the route with $p'$ to show separability, I would just notice that the roots of $p$ are $X$ and $X+1$. This shows immediately that the extension is separable (because $p$ has no repeated roots) and that it's normal (because all roots are in $L$).

Comment: You're welcome.